# 2D Collision with .intersects() in JavaFX - Bad accuracy

Tags: java, javafx, 2d, collision-detection

I have several Shape objects - `Circle`, `Rectangle` and `Polygon`.

I use the built-in `.intersects(Bounds1, Bounds2)` method to detect collision but it's quite inaccurate.

Why is the collision accuracy so bad and how can I improve it? The collision detection is REALLY bad for polygon objects. It is literally at least 50 pixels off.

EDIT: Here's my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < shapes.size(); i++) {
    Bounds b1 = shapes.get(i).getBoundsInParent();                          
    Bounds b2 = shapes.get(i).getBoundsInParent();

if (b1.intersects(b2)) {
     //intersection happened and I remove the shapes from the scene
  }
}
```

and this is the code for my `Polygon`s that represent the ArrayList `Shapes`.

```
class Monster {

Polygon poly;

Monster() {
    poly = new Polygon(new double[] { 125.0,15.0,  150.0,30.0,  150.0,60.0,  125.0,75.0,  100.0,60.0,  100.0,30.0 });
    }
 }
```

Comment: I have never experienced any inaccuracy with JavaFX bounds intersection.  Please edit your question to include a [minimum, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @jewelsea done! Added the code that represents my Monster class + collision detection.

Comment: Thanks Gregg, can you make it something I can copy and paste to compile and run.

Comment: It seems like you are not testing the *polygons* for intersections, but their *bounds* (that is, bounding rectangles). And of course, depending on the shape of the polygons, these rectangles may be arbitrarily bad approximations of the actual shape. Intersecting two polygons can be difficult. One approach could be to transform both polygons into a common coordinate system (e.g. with `getLocalToSceneTransform`) and then *mutually* check `if (polyA.intersects(boundsOfB) && polyB.intersects(boundsOfA)) { ... }`. But I'm not sooo familiar with JavaFX, so this is only a first guess.

Answer (score 0):

From what you posted, you are setting the radius of the `Circle` and then the width and height of the `Rectangle`. But you haven't specified the locations. Perhaps that is your issue?

Try using constructors with `x` and `y` coordinates as well and see if that improves the collision detection.

So like

```
Circle c1 = new Circle(10,10,20); // center at (10,10), radius of 20
Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(10,10,20,20); // upper left corner at (10,10), height and width of 20
```